# Getting Certificate of A WebSite via C#

Tags: c#, ssl, cryptography

I can simply display the certificate with this code. My question is that how can I store or write the certificate in a file?

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

//Do webrequest to get info on secure site
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mail.google.com");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();

//retrieve the ssl cert and assign it to an X509Certificate object
X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;

//convert the X509Certificate to an X509Certificate2 object by passing it into the constructor
X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

string cn = cert2.GetIssuerName();
string cedate = cert2.GetExpirationDateString();
string cpub = cert2.GetPublicKeyString();

//display the cert dialog box
X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(cert2);
```

Comment: You can call cert.Export(...) to a byte[] and write that to a file. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxz81eb9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: How should I fill the parameters? , I do not have a password or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `cert.Export(...)` to get a `byte[]` that you can write to a file.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the X509Store class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

There is a pretty good sample there for how to use it (duplicated here):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.IO;

public class X509store2
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        //Create new X509 store called teststore from the local certificate store.
        X509Store store = new X509Store ("teststore", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open (OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2 ();

        //Create certificates from certificate files. 
        //You must put in a valid path to three certificates in the following constructors.
        X509Certificate2 certificate1 = new X509Certificate2 ("c:\\mycerts\\*****.cer");
        X509Certificate2 certificate2 = new X509Certificate2 ("c:\\mycerts\\*****.cer");
        X509Certificate2 certificate5 = new X509Certificate2 ("c:\\mycerts\\*****.cer");

        //Create a collection and add two of the certificates.
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection ();
        collection.Add (certificate2);
        collection.Add (certificate5);

        //Add certificates to the store.
        store.Add (certificate1);
        store.AddRange (collection);

        X509Certificate2Collection storecollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
        Console.WriteLine ("Store name: {0}", store.Name);
        Console.WriteLine ("Store location: {0}", store.Location);
        foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in storecollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("certificate name: {0}",x509.Subject);
        }

        //Remove a certificate.
        store.Remove (certificate1);
        X509Certificate2Collection storecollection2 = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
        Console.WriteLine ("{1}Store name: {0}", store.Name, Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in storecollection2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("certificate name: {0}", x509.Subject);
        }

        //Remove a range of certificates.
        store.RemoveRange (collection);
        X509Certificate2Collection storecollection3 = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
        Console.WriteLine ("{1}Store name: {0}", store.Name, Environment.NewLine);
        if (storecollection3.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Store contains no certificates.");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in storecollection3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("certificate name: {0}", x509.Subject);
            }
        }

        //Close the store.
        store.Close ();
    }   
}
```